# Perl & CFD-Post: Calculating the average of a sequence of numbers on the fly to an output file using Perl

Tags: perl, printf, average

I’m using a software called CFD-Post to manipulate simulation results. The software command language is based on Perl. So, I’m writing a simple code which contains the software's own commands besides Perl commands to output a data file that contains pressure maximum values at different locations and time intervals. The simplified code example looks something like:

```
# Output file for storing the pressure values from the software. The file is opened here to insert headings.
!   $outputfile = "pressure.txt";
!   open(FH,">> $outputfile");
#   Print headings
!   print FH "time [s]  location    distance [mm]   Max Pressure [Pa]\n";
#########################################################################
#   Loop for creating locations
!   for ($i = 0; $i < 101; $i += 10) {
!   $location = "x${i}"; 
#   ......
#   Code within CFD-Post software for creating the locations for 
    extracting 
    spatial data 
#   ......
#   Code within CFD-Post software for loading different timesteps and 
    looping 
    over them at each location
#   Get the timestep values from the current results file
!   $timestepList = getValue("DATA READER", "Timestep List");
!   @timesteps = split(/, /, $timestepList );
#   Loop over timesteps
!   foreach $ts ( @timesteps ) {
#   Load current timestep, 
>   load timestep=$ts
!   $time = getValue( "DATA READER", "Current Timevalue");
#   ......
#   Code within CFD-Post software for retrieving the pressure value at each 
    location
!   $MaxPressure = maxVal(“Pressure” , "$location");
    ######################################################################
#
#   Perl code of concern in the current question 
    #   Tab delimited output
!   print FH "$time $location   $i  $MaxPressure\n";
!   };
!   };
#   Close the output file 
!   close FH;
```

The ouput in the text file is something like this:

```
time [s]    location    distance [mm]   Max Pressure [Pa]
1           x0          0               3.531e5
2           x0          0               7.795e5
3           x0          0               5.265e5
..          ..          ..              ..
..          ..          ..              ..
10          x0          0               ..e5
1           x10         10              4.267e5
2           x10         10              9.987e5
3           x10         10              1.443e5
..          ..          ..              ..
..          ..          ..              ..
10          x10         10              ..e5
```

What I want is another output text file (on the fly) that ***averages the pressure*** over ***time*** at ***each fixed location***, such that the output will look as:

```
Distance [mm]   Avg Pressure [Pa]
0               x.xxxe5
10              x.xxxe5
20              x.xxxe5 
..              ..e5
```

What will be the Perl code to accomplish this (without using modules?, as I am not sure if they are compatible with the command language used in the software). Of course it is possible to use Matlab to do this task, but I guess it shouldn't be a big issue in Perl? Note that I'm not familiar with Perl, it is the first week that I'm using it :)

#### Update

Here's the above code withe the intrusive comments removed and proper indentation added

```
$outputfile = "pressure.txt";

open( FH, ">> $outputfile" );

print FH "time [s]  location    distance [mm]   Max Pressure [Pa]\n";

for ( $i = 0; $i < 101; $i += 10 ) {

    $location = "x${i}";

    $timestepList = getValue( "DATA READER", "Timestep List" );
    @timesteps    = split( /, /, $timestepList );

    foreach $ts ( @timesteps ) {

        $time        = getValue( "DATA READER", "Current Timevalue" );
        $MaxPressure = maxVal( "Pressure", "$location" );

        print FH "$time $location   $i  $MaxPressure\n";
    }
}

close FH;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is here to help you get your code working. If you don't have any code then you've missed out an important step!

Comment: I see that I have misunderstood your question, but I am still no wiser. You say *"What I want is another output text file (on the fly)"* which sounds like you want real time output. But surely your simulation doesn't work in real time? And even if it does, asking for real time data in a text file is very odd, as text files can normally only be appended to. Also, your code fetches only 11 values from `DATA READER` and it seems odd to want real time data from such a small sample. If you can guarantee that the data will arrive in `distance` order then perhaps something can be done. Please advise.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you a lot for your reply, and I'm very sorry for the confusion. What I meant by _"on the fly"_ is that I want to calculate the average values and save then in a new file within the code itself, without needing to import the data file and write a separate code for the averaging. I have almost zero experience in Perl.
I have tried to run the code you provided, and write the output of average values to a new file `OUT2`, but for some reason it didn't work! I get an empty file.....(cont.)

Comment: I have used `OUT1` instead of `DATA`, since it is containing the data produced by the software (wonder if that is correct to use?)

 `use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
use List::Util 'sum';
my %data;
while ( <OUT1> ) {
    my ($t, $loc, $dist, $maxp) = split;
    next unless looks_like_number($maxp);
    push @{ $data{$dist} }, $maxp;
}
for my $dist ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data ) {
    my $maxp = $data{$dist};
    $maxp = sum(@$maxp) / @$maxp;
    printf OUT2 "%-16d%-.3E\n", $dist, $maxp;
}`
...(cont)

Comment: I guess the software doesn't understand the used modules, but it does not produce any errors. Perhaps  there is a more direct way to avoid using modules? 
I have few hundred of these data points, I'm just now working with a sample of them to see if the code works :)
Cheers!

Comment: You need to `open` file handles before you use them: `open OUT1, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!` (although `OUT1` is a bad name for an input file handle) and rather than opening an output file, you should write to `STDOUT` as my code does, and redirect the output on the bash command line.

Comment: The modules are fine. Both of those are core modules that are part of Perl itself. Your worry about *"I am not sure if they are compatible with the command language used in the software"* I think is unfounded; the command language would have to be *very* strange to have an effect on the internals of Perl. Also, Perl open four standard file handles for you: `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR`, like most languages, and `DATA` which allows you to read from the program file itself. If you add a `__DATA__` marker at the end of your code then anything after it can be read from `DATA`.

Comment: Anything other than those must be opened explicitly within the program as I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Here's your code updated to do what I think you want. It writes two output files instead of one: `pressure.txt` and  `avg.txt`. I have also fixed a few instances of bad practice in your code; in particular you should have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program (I've left them out here because I don't know what the top of your program looks like) and you need to declare all your variables at their first point of use with `my`

I've also changed the open mode for your output file from append. I presume you don't want each output added to the end of the file?

I hope this helps

```
my ( $outputfile, $avg_file ) = qw/ pressure.txt avg.txt /;

open my $out_fh, '>', $outputfile" or die qq{Unable to open "$outputfile" for output: $!};;
open my $avg_fh, '>', $avg_file"   or die qq{Unable to open "$avg_file" for output: $!};;

print $out_fh "time [s]  location    distance [mm]   Max Pressure [Pa]\n";
print $avg_fh "Distance [mm]   Avg Pressure [Pa]\n";

for ( 0 .. 10 ) {

    my $i = $_ * 10;  # $i = 0, 10, 20, ... 100

    my $location = "x$i";

    my $timestep_list = getValue( 'DATA READER', 'Timestep List' );
    my @timesteps    = split /,\s*/, $timestep_list;

    my ($n, $total_maxp) = (0, 0);

    for my $ts ( @timesteps ) {

        my $time         = getValue( 'DATA READER', 'Current Timevalue' );
        my $max_pressure = maxVal( 'Pressure', $location );

        print $out_fh "$time $location   $i  $max_pressure\n";

        ++$n;
        $total_maxp += $max_pressure;
    }

    printf $avg_fh "%-16d%-.3e\n", $i, $total_maxp / $n;
}

close $out_fh or die $!;
close $avg_fh or die $!;
```

#### Original answer

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
use List::Util 'sum';

my %data;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ($t, $loc, $dist, $maxp) = split;
    next unless looks_like_number($maxp);
    push @{ $data{$dist} }, $maxp;
}

for my $dist ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data ) {
    my $maxp = $data{$dist};
    $maxp = sum(@$maxp) / @$maxp;
    printf "%-16d%-.3E\n", $dist, $maxp;
}

__DATA__
time [s]    location    distance [mm]   Max Pressure [Pa]
1           x0          0               3.531e5
2           x0          0               7.795e5
3           x0          0               5.265e5
..          ..          ..              ..
..          ..          ..              ..
10          x0          0               ..e5
1           x10         10              4.267e5
2           x10         10              9.987e5
3           x10         10              1.443e5
..          ..          ..              ..
..          ..          ..              ..
10          x10         10              ..e5
```

#### output

```
0               5.530E+005
10              5.232E+005
```

Comment: The original answer that was posted works well. It just needed that the file containing the calculated output values be opened before manipulation of the code posted in the answer starts. 
Also, this is a confirmation that modules work in CFD-Post session file. I have found that the Perl version used is perl-5.9.5-vs2k12 (Comes with ANSYS 17.0)